# How can I replace word in text files without pushing word that come after far away?

Tags: c#

I want to replace some word in text file but after I've use regex.replace method the problem is a next word that come after I've replace has push away from original position. How can I fix position of the next word?

For example, my text file is

```
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
Address: ~ADDRESS                 Date:~DOCUMENTDATE
```

After replace,

```
Address: 123/999 New York                 **Date:02/01/2019**
```

You'll see Date:02/01/2019 has move from original position, How can I fix position of Date: after finish replace?

My code is...

```
string tmp = string.Empty;
tmp = Regex.Replace(tmp, @"(?<=^|\s)" + "~ADDRESS" + @"(?=\s|$)", "123/999 New York");
File.WriteAllText("D:\\" + "form.txt", tmp, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-874"));
```

Comment: also, why to use `Regex`? Why not to `tmp.Replace("~ADDRESS", "123/999 New York")`?

Comment: No, John, it's plain text file which use white space between words.

Comment: vasily.sib, I already try that but it made same result.

Comment: `"123/999 New York".Length > "~ADDRESS".Length`

Comment: sure, and that result is correct. You transform "Address: ~ADDRESS`[Exactly 17 whitespaces]`Date:~DOCUMENTDATE" to "Address: 123/999 New York`[Exactly 17 whitespaces]`Date:02/01/2019" what is wrong here?

Comment: Brian Rasmussen , vasily.sib, I know that logic but is it has any way to made this possible? I want to replace word in formatted text file which need to fix position of every word in file.

Comment: Is the size for each line fixed? If the line is shorter than 60 characters, will it be padded with space?

Comment: please, add `@` symbol before username so we can receive notifications. There is [PadLeft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [PadRight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padright?view=netframework-4.7.2) methods, that might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is realy simple: you need to replace ~ADDRESS`[Exactly 17 whitespaces]` with actial address padded to match pattern lenght. So lets just write this (literally):

```
const string ADDRESS_PATTERN = "~ADDRESS                 ";
const string DOCUMENTDATE_PATTERN = "~DOCUMENTDATE";

var text = "123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890\r\n" +
           "Address: ~ADDRESS                 Date: ~DOCUMENTDATE";
var actualAddress = "123/999 New York";
var actualDate = "02/01/2019";

text = text.Replace(ADDRESS_PATTERN, actualAddress.PadRight(ADDRESS_PATTERN.Length));    
text = text.Replace(DOCUMENTDATE_PATTERN, actualDate.PadRight(DOCUMENTDATE_PATTERN.Length));

Console.WriteLine(text);
// 123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
// Address: 123/999 New York         Date: 02/01/2019
```

Comment: ~ADDRESS pattern with a lot of spaces looks as not very good hack imho

Comment: Thanks @vasily.sib, I'll give a try and back to tell result asap.

Comment: @woldemar few moments before you told, that this is "nice hack":) Any way, I don't think this is a "hack". I'm just telling, that pattern for address is not just `~ADDRESS` but also some whitespaces after

Comment: @vasily.sib I mean it is not very good idea to hardcode whitespaces in pattern, if one space will be removed from file, you should change pattern too.

Comment: @woldemar well, that is true, but this whitespaces are **already** in a pattern. For example, when you will be needed to leave exactly 3 whitespaces before `"Date: ~DOCUMENTDATE"` your code will need change too.

Comment: @vasily.sib, back to thanks again, it work. I just modified the logic for find length of  white space of actual address and concatenate with that placeholder, and then replace it.

Comment: @vasily.sib sorry, but I can't understand how my code will be needed to changed..